# SQL case and categorizes

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have dataset which contains differen populations of different cities. I need to do table like that picture. [image]

So "amount" is how many cities is in that category.

So far I have this:

```
SELECT COUNT(name) AS AMOUNT,
       CASE
            WHEN population > 5000000 THEN 'Over 5 miljon'
            WHEN population > 1000000
             AND population < 4999999 THEN '1 000 000 - 4 999 999'
            WHEN population > 500000
             AND population < 999999 THEN '500 000 - 999 999'
            WHEN population > 100000
             AND population < 499999 THEN '100 000 - 499 999'
            WHEN population < 100000 THEN 'Below 100 000'
       END AS Category
FROM cities;
```

Now that "count(name)" counts all the cities.

Comment: You should spend more time on your posts, the formatting was terrible. And do you mean MySQL **or** SQL Server?

Comment: MySQL and SQL Server are 2 different RDBMS. Which one are you actually using? I've removed both tags, please edit your post and include on the tag for the RDBMS you are using. (I'm guessing MySQL by the fact that that query would fail in SQL Server due to the lack of a `GROUP BY` clause.)

Comment: sorry I use sql

Comment: We know you use sql. The question is WHICH DBMS are you using?

Comment: SQL isn't a RDBMS. Every RDBMS uses it's own "flavour" of SQL. For example SQL Server uses T-SQL, Oracle uses PL\SQL. We need to know what RDBMS you are using.

Comment: So I am using SQLite

Comment: So neither of the RDBMS you initially tagged. Knowing which RDBMS you are using in incredibly important; if you donj't know what one you are using, then writing correct SQL for your environment is very hard. None of them completely support the ISO standards, and then depending on the version of the RDBMS they may support less, plus they each have different functions.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(name) AS AMOUNT, 
    Category 
FROM
    (SELECT
         name,      
         CASE
            WHEN population > 5000000 THEN 'Over 5 miljon'
            WHEN population > 1000000
             AND population < 4999999 THEN '1 000 000 - 4 999 999'
            WHEN population > 500000
             AND population < 999999 THEN '500 000 - 999 999'
            WHEN population > 100000
             AND population < 499999 THEN '100 000 - 499 999'
            WHEN population < 100000 THEN 'Below 100 000'
        END AS Category
    FROM 
        cities) t
GROUP BY
    Category;
```

You need to find the category for each city, and then count cities belonging to the same category. The inner query, finds the category:

```
select name,      CASE
            WHEN population > 5000000 THEN 'Over 5 miljon'
            WHEN population > 1000000
             AND population < 4999999 THEN '1 000 000 - 4 999 999'
            WHEN population > 500000
             AND population < 999999 THEN '500 000 - 999 999'
            WHEN population > 100000
             AND population < 499999 THEN '100 000 - 499 999'
            WHEN population < 100000 THEN 'Below 100 000'
       END AS Category
FROM cities
```

And the outer query does the count.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add your CASE to a group by clause in your select, like this:

```
select 
   case .... end as category,
   count(*) as amount
from
  cities
group by
  case .... end
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to create a virtualized or physical table of your boundary values to remove the need to change the query when exploring different boundary sets. If you are using SQL Server then you could use a table variable for the few values similar to below.

```
DECLARE @Boundries TABLE(LowValue INT, HighValue INT, Decription NVARCHAR(500))
INSERT @Boundries VALUES (1,99999,'Below 100 000'),(100000,499999,'100 000 - 499 999'),(500000,999999,'500 000 - -999 999'),(1000000,4999999,'1 000 000 - 4 999 999'),(5000000,1000000000,'Over 5 Million')

;WITH Data As
(
    SELECT Name,Population = COUNT(*)
    FROM cities
    GROUP BY Name
)  
SELECT D.Name,D.Population,B.Decription
FROM
    Data D
    INNER JOIN @Boundries B ON D.Population BETWEEN B.LowValue AND B.HighValue
```